# NoClassDefError while getting EntityManagerFactory instance

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jpa

I am building an android application with app engine backend.But to insert entity to the datastore, I am unable to get entitymanagefactoy(EMF) instance as it throws NoClassDefFound Error.I have tried almost all solutions suggested in earlier questions.

Eclipse version:4.2.0
Using Jre7
and using apengine-java-sdk-1.8.8

The EMF class generated by Google plugin:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public final class EMF {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private EMF() {
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mark dependencies in java build path -> order and export? 
Also, I had similar problem once with 3rd libraries requiring own dependencies that has been resolved by eclipse, but didnt work in runtime as they were included in main project not libraries themselves.

Comment: It was problem with the jpa version.I changed it to version 1 and it worked.